# Hyperref: using abbreviated labels like Eq., but keep correct spacing after period

Tags: hyperref

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\equationautorefname}{Eq.}
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
  x = 3.
\end{equation}
My reference to \autoref{eq1}.
\end{document}
```

produces output like "see Eq. 1" where the spacing will be an end-of-sentence spacing. Normally I would type something like `Eq.\ 1` to prevent this. How to achieve this?

Comment: Don't show only snippets, make a complete example that can be tested directly.

Comment: I don't get an end of sentence space, I get the same spacing as `Eq.~1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is clearly an normal space (non-breaking) and not an end-of-sentence space. If you want a smaller space you can define the name to take an argument so that it "eats" this space, and replace it by e.g. \,:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\equationautorefname}{Eq.}
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
  x = 3.
\end{equation}
My reference to  \autoref{eq1}.   %normal, non-breaking

\noindent My reference to Eq.\ 1. %normal

\noindent My reference to Eq. 1.  %end of sentence

\renewcommand{\equationautorefname}[1]{Eq.\,}

\noindent My reference to \autoref{eq1}. %small
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that.